# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pygame.math.Vector2' and 'int'

Tags: python, vector, pygame, runtime-error, operands

I don't know what's going on and I can't find anyone else with the same issue.
Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import math
import random
import os

SWIDTH = 800
SHEIGHT = 600
vec = pygame.math.Vector2
FRI = 0.3
ACC = 1
```

this is the error

```
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\games\GAME.py", line 137, in update
self.loc += self.vel + 1 + self.aird
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pygame.math.Vector2' and 'int'

Comment: Part of the code is missing from the question.

Comment: I am guessing you are adding an integer to a vector. Either add it to one of the parts of the vector (vec.x or vec.y) or make it a vector and add it that way.

Comment: This code does not produce that error. Post the full error message (which tells you exactly which line the error is on) and a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`self.vel` is a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html). You cannot add an integral number to the object.

You can sum up 2 vectors:

```py
self.loc += self.vel
```

Or you can add a value (scalar) to the components of a vector:

```py
self.loc.x += self.vel.x + 1
self.loc.y += self.vel.y + 1
```